# How to change date format dmYhis to Y-m-d in PHP

Tags: php

How to change date format dmYhis to Y-m-d in PHP. I have using the date() function  but I cannot seem to make it work

```
   $d = '24032017191551';

   echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($d));
```

Output: 1970-01-01

i want to get the ans is 2017-03-24

Comment: This is not correct duplicate! He is going above the 32 bit limit of strtotime(). See here https://3v4l.org/UHWTB

Comment: @HankyPanky ? Reopen and let me answer the question. None of the answers on the page you link to is correct for this question

Comment: That suggestion is not the correct answer. There is no 32 bit limit in action here. You're assuming that they are proving a Unix timestamp, they are not. Its an improperly formatted datetime. '24032017191551' => `24-03-2017 19:15:51`. That Fiddle is misguided.

Comment: @Hanky i see that now. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Below is the code to change date format**

```
      $retrieved ='24032017191551';
      $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('dmYHis', $retrieved);
      echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: $date=date_create("24032017191551");
echo date_format($date,"Y/m/d");i got thi s error :date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, boolean given on line 2

Comment: @AparnaPM..can u tell me the format of the date u are entering..

Comment: date('dmYhis') format

Comment: Your answer is not correct, you just changed the input to fit the date he wants. I usually don't downvote but this is really bad.

Comment: @Andreas...she has not mentioned that she requires hour as well as minutes....then its not a problem...

Comment: @Andreas..if u have better suggestion then please post it'll improve my programming skill also...

Comment: @Pradeep I'm not talking about the output. I'm talking about you substr(..., 0, 8). You take the value and just delete the last 6 digits to make it correct. I have written what is the issue with this question above in comments but since HankyPanky closed the question I can not post an answer to the question.

Comment: @Andreas..I hope now the answer is ok..because ive tested it and got desired output...

Comment: This answer, as it currently stands, is the correct answer for the (duplicate) question being asked.

Comment: @AparnaPM...since uve not accepted my answer...i hope my answer was helpful in clearing the error..